# MVC ViewModel approaches and mapping. Best approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, mass-assignment, valueinjecter

I've been looking at the different approaches to solving the mass assignment issues with MVC as well as doing things the right way.

So far, the 2 approaches which I think are the best are below: (I have also looked at AutoMapper)

1: Value Injecter - This seems to do the job pretty well, but also relies on a third party library

2: Using the UpdateModel method and bind to a View Model interface which exposes a subset of the required properties in your domain model. http://www.codethinked.com/easy-and-safe-model-binding-in-aspnet-mvc

Before I jump in and code my whole application (without spending a week on each to find out which one I actually like) using one of the above practices, does anybody have real world experience of using these 2 methods and which one you would recommend?

Comment: This looks like a subjective question - please check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Thanks for that helpful response

Answer (score 0):

in simple scenarios where you have only text fields matching strings/int properties anything will do just as well.

but when you have properties on the viewmodel that match objects in the model (FK in the DB) it gets a bit more complex, you might need to pull data from the DB for some individual props and map some property of that object to the ViewModel, stuff like that.

prodinner asp.net mvc demo application uses valueinjecter in Mapper classes, there's a pdf where this approach is explained, you can download it here: http://prodinner.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

General consensus from all the reading I've done on this topic is that if you're going from a Entity or Domain Model (from your database) to a View Model to show on the form feel free to use automation tools like AutoMapper or whatever your preferred tool is to automate it.

If you are however going from a Input or Form Model (the object populated via the automatic model binding) back into to your Entity or Domain Model, do not automate this. It's a slippery slope to navigate correctly and can result in your automation tool mapping over fields that were not intended/permitted. Everything I've read about this (and various implementations myself) suggest the best practice is to do this manually/explicitly. It's pretty straight forward and object initializers can make it very easy to read.

```
var person = new Person()
{
    PersonId = model.PersonId,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName= model.LastName
}

personService.UpdatePerson(person);
```

Something along that line.